# Год Господень вместо привычного лето Господне - возможно?

Tags: выбор-слов

> ...Указал на фасаде: “Климент XII понтифик украсил акведук девы и
>   освятил его великолепие богослужением в год Господень 1735, в шестой
>   год своего понтификата”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Год Господень* вместо привычного *лето Господне* - возможно?

**Конечно возможно.** [**См. примеры:**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=RNv7WNSlD8Oe6ATw95DAAg#q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks)

*Счет годов нашей эры (от Рождества Христова, в Западной Европе применяются слова «год господень» — Аnnо Domini, сокращенно АD) был предложен в VI в., а широко применяться стал только с XVI в.*

*В год Господень 892... в понедельник (17 апреля) перед Пасхой нас постигло невосполнимое несчастье.*

*В год господень 1219 избран был королем Иоанн, сын короля Сверкера...*

*Когда я явился на этот берег в год Господень тысяча семьсот первый, здесь находилось несколько рыбаков...*

*На протяжении столетий цивилизованный мир делил историю на периоды «до Р. Х.» и Anno Domini, «в год Господень».*

*В год господень 1198 достопочтенный Альберт, каноник бременский, был...*

*В год господень тысяча двести сорок первый татары пришли в Руссию и до основания разрушили обширнейший город Киев, великолепную столицу русских.*

*Из протокола заседания: «Далее, в следующую затем субботу, в последний день месяца марта, накануне Пасхи, в год Господень 1431…"*

> Константин Душенко *"Религия и этика в изречениях и цитатах:
>   Справочник":*
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

А по-моему, так говорят, вернее, пишут.

Если вспомнить, откуда что  пришло, в основу летосчисления на Руси после принятия в 988 году христианства был положен пришедший к нам через Византию юлианский календарь с римскими наименованиями месяцев и семидневной неделей.Тогда же вошла в употребление  и  византийская мировая эра, в которой сотворение мира относилось к  5508  году до н. э.

Сегодня почти во всех уголках нашей планеты летосчисление ведется от «рождества Христова». Эта эра была введена в 525 г. римским монахом, папским архивариусом, скифом по происхождению, Дионисием Малым. Часто год по этой эре обозначают буквами AD, что на латинском языке означает Anno Domini — «года Господа», но чаще всего говорят «такого-то года нашей эры», так как эта эра является совершенно условной.  Так что "год Господень"="год Господа" вполне употребимо. 1735г.- это же нашей эры, от рождества Христова, значит,правильно год Господень 1735

http://www.uhlib.ru/istorija/vedastinskie_annaly_annaly_sen_vaasta/p1.php

http://vashaktiv.ru/texts/v/venecia.php

Comment: По-моему, здесь налицо смешение двух совершенно разных вещей. Год от Рождества Господа (нашего Иисуса Христа) - A. D. и "Лета Господня" - года от сотворения мира. Как-то даже не приходило в голову, что эти вещи можно так спутать... Вот чуть подробнее о самом выражении http://vichuga-voskr.cerkov.ru/2016/02/19/chto-znachit-leto-gospodne/

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае. Здесь надо всё менять. Лето Господне - форма устоявшаяся, хотя и используется сейчас преимущественно по отношению к русской/православной действительности.

Но самое главное: эта форма требует отсчета `лет **от сотворения мира**, иное смотрится нелепо, это ж не "лето Господне", а совсем другой счет. Здесь требуется "в год 1735-й от рождества Христова" (Anno Domini).

(======================)

Вот нашел тут кое-что из источника, который я счел авторитетным.

> Наше летосчисление = эра "от Рождества Христова"
>
> ПРЕДВАРЕНИЯ
>
> Как уже отмечалось, эра "от Рождества Христова" была введена post
>   factum "кончиком пера". Впервые от Рождества Христова (в латинской
>   традиции - "Anno Domini" (AD) - "года Господня") был обозначен год,
>   который стал 525-м годом нового летосчисления.
>
> Эра была создана римским монахом, папским архивариусом, скифом по
>   происхождению Дионисием Малым. Никаких сведений о том, на основании
>   каких расчётов и соображений это было сделано, не имеется. Поэтому
>   относительно схемы перехода на новое летосчисление предлагаются
>   различные догадки, хотя ни одна из них не представляется убедительнее
>   другой. Доподлинно известно лишь то, что связано это было с
>   подготовкой пасхальных таблиц (пасхалии) на дальнейшую перспективу.
>
> По сложившейся в свете решений Никейского Собора 325 года церковной
>   традиции, христианская Пасха должна отмечаться в первое воскресенье
>   после первого полнолуния после весеннего равноденствия. В связи с
>   несоразмерностью солнечного и лунного циклов, которым она
>   сопоставляется, дата праздника с годами смещается по временной шкале в
>   пределах с 22 марта по 25 апреля по юлианскому календарю. Практически
>   на каждый год она определяется расчётным путём.
>
> При составлении пасхалий днём весеннего равноденствия с 325 года
>   принято было считать 21 марта по юлианскому календарю. В основание
>   расчётов пасхальных фаз Луны на каждый год был положен относительно
>   точный 19-летний лунный цикл, открытый великим греческим астрономом
>   Метоном в 432 - олимпийском - году до н.э. Как было установлено,
>   каждые 19 лет все фазы Луны приходятся на те же числа месяца
>   солнечного года. Это так называемый "круг Луны".
>
> С другой стороны, в юлианском календаре каждые 28 лет все числа месяца
>   приходятся на те же самые дни недели. Это так называемый "круг
>   Солнца".
>
> Поскольку 19 и 28 - числа некратные, то все (расчётные!) фазы Луны
>   совпадают с теми же числами месяца и днями недели через период
>   времени, равный произведению 19 х 28, то есть через 532 года. Поэтому
>   каждые 532 года (этот период называется великим индиктионом)
>   повторяются и расчётные даты пасхальных воскресений. В современной
>   традиции индиктионы принято отсчитывать от исходного момента
>   византийской эры - от 5508 года до Р.Х. В настоящее время идёт 15-й
>   великий индиктион, который начался в 1941 году.
>
> Исходя из практических соображений, при разработке пасхальных таблиц
>   пользовались менее точным, но более удобным 95-летним (= 19 х 5)
>   циклом (это так называемый малый пасхальный круг). По обычаю,
>   восходящему к началу IV века, такие таблицы подготавливались
>   пасхалистами Александрийской Церкви и затем рассылались по всему
>   христианскому миру.

Из чего я делаю вывод, что дохристианское понятие "Лета Господня № такой-то" все-таки было частично перенесено на летоисчисление "*Года Господа* от Р. Х." (АD)

*Не знаю, насколько это основание достаточно, но фиксация действительно имеется.* Но все равно во избежание недоразумений я бы от Р.Х. (или AD) не отказывался.

(======================)

С другой стороны, форма **"1735-го Лета Христова"** снимает все разночтения, но я как-то не встречал её применительно к событиям относительно недавнего прошлого.

Comment: Ой-ё! Что ж делать-то?! Может, на итальянском 1735 года возможно было *в год Господень 1735*?

Comment: Насчет итальянского. Я не владею вопросом, но очень сомневаюсь, что дело тут в языке, а не в общем христианском менталитете.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova в 1735 г. все кроме иудеев отсчитывали летосчисление от сотворения мира не использовали, поэтому, да, год Господень здесь неуместно. Если автор хочет "закоса" под старину, то можно для использовать римские цифры (MDCCXXХV), года в те времена записывали так.

Comment: Марк, если я стребую с автора эту фразу на латыни - поможете? А пока - Anno Domini MDCCXXХV, да?

Comment: Моя уверенность несколько поколебалась, я существенно дополнил ответ.